# "Unable to load http://url status:0" error in onbeforeunload-method

Tags: javascript, xpages, lotus-domino, lotus

may someone of you can help me to find this problem?

I've got an xpage with client-side js-code included which should be executed when you decide to leave the page. In the client-side js you refer to a button and click it automatically. This button got some server-side js code included and change the flag from a document from ("opened by ..." to "").

The thing is that somehow the client-side js did not work in all different browsers except the current IE (10.0.5) and throws the error:

```
unable to load http://urlofthedocument/... status:0
```

The funny thing about this is, when I insert an alert()-method right after the click()-method everything works fine in every browser. But as I don't want to include this alert statement I figure out there must be something different to avoid this. (A short pause instead of the alert-method also did not work.)

My CS JS-Code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = WarnEditMode;

function WarnEditMode(){
    if(needUnloadConfirm == true){
        var el = window.document.getElementById("#{id:Hidden4SSJS}");
        el.click();
        //document.open();
        //document.write(el);
        //document.close();
        //alert("You're about to leave the page");
        //pause(5000);

    }
}

function pause(millis){
    var date = new Date();
    var curDate = null;
    do { curDate = new Date(); }
    while(curDate-date < millis)
}
```

This refers to to button, which executes following SS JS code, after it is clicked:

```
try{
    print("Hidden4SSJS-Button-Test @ Person");
    var db:NotesDatabase = database;
    var agt:NotesAgent;
    var doc:NotesDocument = XPPersonDoc.getDocument()

    agt = db.getAgent("(XPUnlockDocument)");
    agt.run(doc.getNoteID());
}catch(e){
    _dump(e);
}
```

May you guys can help me with this?

Comment: I already got it on my own.

You just have to catch the error somewhere in your code by using

    XSP.error = function(e){
       window.document.getElementById("#{id:Hidden4SSJS}").click();
    };

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using the XSP object with a hidden computed field (and not your special button)...

Something like this:

```
function WarnEditMode(){
   if(needUnloadConfirm == true){
      XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:unlockDocCF1}", {
         params: {
            '$$xspsubmitvalue': 'needToUnlock'
         },
         onComplete: function () {
            alert('You are about to leave this page and the document has been unlocked.');
         },
         onError : function (e) {
            alert('You are about to leave this page and the document has NOT been unlocked.\n' + e);
         }
      );
   }
  pause(5000);
}
```

Then the computed field's javascript would be something like this:

```
try{
    var sval = @Explode(context.getSubmittedValue(), ',');
    if (sval == null) return result + " no action.";
    if (!"needToUnlock".equals(sval[0])) return result + " no action.";

    print("Hidden4SSJS-Button-Test @ Person");
    var db:NotesDatabase = database;
    var agt:NotesAgent;
    var doc:NotesDocument = XPPersonDoc.getDocument()

    agt = db.getAgent("(XPUnlockDocument)");
    agt.run(doc.getNoteID());
    return 'document unlocked.';
}catch(e){
    _dump(e);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately this solution is only working for IE and Firefox and not with Chrome, Safari or Opera. My solution with the click-button is working with Chrome as well. I haven't found a better solution which could also make Opera or Safari get to work.